# Retryable Exception in Flows

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, platform-event

I have a Flow that calls an Apex Action, which in case of failure throws an EventBus.RetryableException:

```
if(EventBus.TriggerContext.currentContext().retries < calloutSettings.Number_of_Retries__c){
    throw new EventBus.RetryableException(e.getMessage());
} else {
    ... handle failure ...
}
```

However, in my debug log this is coming out as: `10:08:20:803 FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR An Apex error occurred: eventbus.RetryableException: TEST_ERROR`

Is there any way I can throw a RetryableException in a way that it works when the entry point is a Flow?

Comment: Is this code in a EventBus trigger? If not, you can't. As such, this may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It may well be, I'm just surprised you can throw Retryable Exceptions from Apex triggers but not from Apex called by platform-event triggered Flows! :-)